# Difference between a 'condo' and a 'condominium'

Tags: meaning, nouns, nuance

They seem to be a really similar words, but I wonder that there is a difference between the two words? Location, size of the house, or facilities in the building?

Comment: I wouldn't describe a condo[minium] as a "house".

Comment: Six letters....

Answer (score 2):

The original word was *condominium*. In popular and casual use it was abbreviated to *condo*. There is no difference in meaning.

The same process of truncating abbreviation happened to photograph/photo, examination/exam, memorandum/memo and many other words. Please note that these truncated abbreviations are not the same as acronyms (PC = Personal Computer) or texting abbreviations (IMHO, In My Humble Opinion)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference except that "condominium" belongs to the current register whereas "condo" is informal (colloquial, in other words). Both words are used synonymously in certain articles ([ref.](https://www.realtor.com/advice/buy/what-is-a-condo/)).